# JavaScript onclick doesn't work except for document.onclick

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I've been trying to learn something about JavaScript today, came across events and somehow I'm stuck at it.

When I call the first function it just works, however if I call the second one it doesn't execute the function for some reason? I've tried doing it without the `windows.onload` event I've tried putting the script code inside head element or just above the closing body tag but nothing has changed, any tips?

```
function peh() {
    
    document.onclick = function(){
    alert("you clicked");
}
}

function second(){
    var myElement = getElementsByTagName("mImg");
    myElement.onclick = function(){
        alert("clicked img");
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    second();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use getElementsByTagName which receives the DOM HTML tag name, say, 'td'
Better use getElementsById, as I guess mImg is an ID of some element...

Comment: yeah, i didn't change that when i copied it here, but it doesn't work with getElementById either

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to change your code like that :

```
function second(){
   var myElement = document.getElementsByTagName("mImg");
   myElement[0].onclick = function(){
    alert("clicked first img");
   }
}
```

Because getElementsByTagName selector is returning array. And you can make it "for" or "while" loop for each element.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jquery framework you will not bother yourself about those things anymore .
just use jquery functions .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(mImg).click(function(){
   alert("goood");
 });
});
```

or for dynamic tags :

```
$(document).on("click","mImg",function(){
alert("goood");
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I know where you are getting :)  The thing is I want to have some basic knowledge and understanding of pure javascript before moving on to jQuery and other frameworks